# Managing state server side to be requested by a hub client

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I have created a really basic hub that I get the `IHubContext` and call the my javascript client side method *via a group so I can always push the data to the same user no matter how many diffrent connections they are on*, which i pass some text to and that text is appended in a multiline textbox in the browser.

It all works really nicely. The thread will typically run long operations, often appending text reporting on the status of the operation using the hub context to call the client.

However, I wish to cater for the situation where someone would close their browser then return later the page with the textbox.

Now at the moment they would just start reciving the text from the point in the operation they connect on. How can I send a request from the client to the server to retrive all the text back from the begining of the operation?

My idea was to have a `StringBuilder` object that i append each line identically as the text I send to the client hub.

Then on connect of the hub call a server side function from the client which asks for the full text which can be taken from the `StringBuilder` object `ToString();`

But how can the hub know where to get the `StringBuilder` object from in the still executing thread?

OR

If there is a way to push it to the client instead, how can I know in the executing thread that the user has connected and send the `StringBuilder` `ToString()` to the user?

NB. I do not want to resend the full string appened every time! Only when the user has just connected and needs to catch up.

I think understanding how to do this would help understand how to deal with signalR and state on the server outside of the hub. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, you should probably store this data in some kind of persistent storage (not just in an in-memory StringBuilder). Regardless of that though, what you really need to do is store the individual strings with timestamps. Then just remember the last time you saw the logical user and dump all entries since that time when they are first connecting to your Hub.

JabbR, the flagship, test bed application for SignalR, does something just like this except it just does it using message ids and asks for all message ids since the last message id the client received. [Check out the Chat Hub's GetPreviousMessages](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR/blob/2ba7231bd6ffc67ebbbfb4595668461ce857bc36/JabbR/Hubs/Chat.cs#L336) for details.